# 301 redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

ok, so i can't tell if this is a server issue or what. i've got an htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/main/index/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)$ /index.php?/main/ajax/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend.php/(.*)$ /backend.php?/$1 [L]

# 301 redirects
Redirect 301 /backup.php http://www.example.com/backup/
Redirect 301 /document.php http://www.example.com/document/
Redirect 301 /contact.php http://www.example.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /links.php http://www.example.com/links/
Redirect 301 /jobs.php http://www.example.com/jobs/
```

the only issue i have is with my 301 redirects. instead of

example.com/backup.php going to example.com/backup/ it instead sends it to example.com/backup/?/main/index/backup.php.

this does route the page properly. meaning i get the proper html returned but the url is ugly. i should say that this IS done in code igniter and that i'm routing EVERYTHING to the ***main*** controller's method ***index*** which makes backup, document, contact, etc the first argument of the index method. this may seem odd - and also may have no relevance - but i need it to be this way. anyone have any suggestions on how to get the redirected urls clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not a good idea to use both mod_alias and mod_rewrite. Try this mod_rewrite rule instead of your `Redirect` directives and put it in front of your current rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(backup|document|contact|links|jobs)\.php$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: interesting...that actually routes /backup.php to /backup.php resulting in a 404 error. :( any other thoughts?

Comment: @ocergynohtna: And you really put this rule as the first rule of your rule set?

Comment: i had it at the bottom where i had the 301's originally, moving it toward the top resolved the issue. Thanks Gumbo!